# Terraform provider Azure - how to manage Identity and Access Management (Azure AD)?

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform-provider-azure

Is it possible to manage users and groups using Terraform?

Operations such as MFA, user-types, Authentication methods, Registration, notification, User settings, group settings, and Device settings.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to manage users and groups using Terraform?

Yes, you can use Terraform to integrate with Azure AD and manage users and groups in Azure AD. At the same time, Terraform supports a number of different methods for authenticating to Azure AD.

Please see:[here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs).

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with this page. Where can I look for Operations such as MFA, user-types, Authentication methods, Registration, notification, User settings, group settings, and Device settings?

Comment: @OmerShliva  Please see the link I provided in the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see there answers to my questions. Where can you see how to add "user_type" for an example?

Comment: This is an example for managing groups: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/group

But it looks like Terraform's level of management might be lower than what you're hoping for.

Comment: You can expand the left navigation bar of the linked document, which lists all the methods that Terraform can manage Azure AD, but, as you can see, it only supports some basic management, and  more advanced management I think it is not yet have.